# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when using mocha to do a unit test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I am using mocha and chai to do a unit test in typescript, this is the dependencies:

```
"@types/mocha": "7.0.2",
"@types/node": "14.0.11",
"@types/chai": "4.2.11",
"chai": "4.2.0",
"mocha": "7.2.0",
```

and this is the `test.ts` file:

```
import { describe } from 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('TaxCalculator', () =>
{
    describe('test calculateTaxAmount(salesPrice, taxRate)', () =>
    {
        it('should calculate the tax for an item', () =>
        {
            // let xxxx = await DeviceHandler.getDeviceId();
            // expect(xxxx === "xxxx")
        });
    });
});
```

the `package.json` command look like this:

```
"test": "mocha -r ./test/utils/* ",
```

when I run the command `yarn test`, shows error like this:

```
$ yarn test                                                                                                                                                                     ‹ruby-2.7.2›
yarn run v1.21.1
$ mocha -r ./test/utils/* 
/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:240
      .concat(Object.keys(yargs.parsed.newAliases) || [])
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.help (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:240:22)
    at Object.self.showHelp (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:432:15)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:53:13)
    at Object.fail (/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:41:17)
    at /Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:246:36
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
(base)
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Currently having the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: yes, I have solved this problem, the demo code you can checkout from: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel @sentientmachine you can check the `DeviceHandler.test.ts`

Comment: Wait this looks the same as mine. What solves the issues?